# ndk-build stays at NDEBUG=1 despite Gradle debuggable: true in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk

I'm having a ton of difficulty trying to get Gradle to compile a debug version of my JNI code through NDK build. I've set the debug build to be debuggable in the `build.gradle` file like so:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable true
    }
}
```

I can confirm that the switches are taking effect if I check out Build/Edit Build types. However, once I check the `ndkBuild_build_command.txt` file inside of the `.externalNdkBuild` directory, I notice the following entries:

```
NDEBUG=1
APP_PLATFORM=android-9
```

I can confirm that my JNI code does not seem to be debuggable. Even though the breakpoints trigger, variables all show "variable not available" in LLVM.

Any ideas as to why NDEBUG is turned on even in a debug build? As a sidenote, I also have no idea where the android-9 platform is entering in... I'm not setting that myself anywhere that I could find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Android Studio 2.2 with **externalNativeBuild**, you can set `APP_OPTIM=debug` in your **Application.mk** or `NDK_DEBUG=1` through parameters override, e.g.

```
externalNativeBuild {
  ndkBuild {
    arguments "NDK_DEBUG:=1"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful -- that's basically what I've settled on. Only using Gradle to set NDK_DEBUG value, and then detecting that value inside of Application.mk to control APP_OPTIM and any additional flags. This build system is an absolute disaster. Any idea why SELECTED_BUILD_VARIANT inside my .iml file would get stuck on "release" instead of "debug"? I am hating Android Studio and Gradle more and more with every hour.

I *still* don't know why NDEBUG=1 is always set to true, debug build or not. But if you *also* define NDK_DEBUG it seems to remove optimizations and *undefine* NDEBUG=1. Insane.

Comment: There is no short answer to your questions/ complaints except "yes". Do you run ndk-build for a *library* module, or for *application*?

Comment: It's for my application module. I'm using Cocos2d-x which is C++ based, so almost *everything* is done within native code. I've managed to get things to a kind of reasonable state. I realized one big thing was that I had to keep hitting "Refresh Linked C++ Projects" for whatever reason. Who was I to think that just asking it to build would work without invalidating caches and restarting Android Studio, cleaning the project, syncing Gradle files, and then refreshing linked projects?!

Comment: This issue was a caused by a bug (https://b.corp.google.com/issues/225273). I fixed it last week and I think it should be in for Android Studio 2.2.3. Once you can upgrade to that version you shouldn't need Alex's excellent workaround.